# Handling XML Data from WebRequest in Powershell

Tags: xml, rest, powershell

```
$uri = "https://${server}/api/${api_version}/xml"
$login_request = "<LoginRequest password ='$pwd' user-id = '$user' ></LoginRequest>"
$resp = Invoke-WebRequest -URI $uri -Body $login_request -ContentType 'text/xml' -Method post
[xml]$xmldata = $resp.content
if($xmldata.LoginResponse.success -eq '0'){
    Write-Host 'ERROR: '$xmldata.LoginResponse.Failure.message -ForegroundColor Red
    }
    Else{
    $SCRIPT:session_id = $xmldata.LoginResponse.'session-id'
    Write-Host "Login Successful" -ForegroundColor Green
    }
$disc_request = "<DiscoveryConnectionListingRequest session-id='$SCRIPT:session_id'/>"
$resp_disc = Invoke-WebRequest -URI $uri -Body $disc_request -ContentType 'text/xml' -Method post
[xml]$xmldata = $resp_disc.content
$xmldata.DiscoveryConnectionListingResponse.DiscoveryConnectionSummary
```

This returns about 30 of these:

```
connection-status : Connected
id                : 58
name              : server1
engine-id         : 59

connection-status : Disconnected
id                : 57
name              : server2
engine-id         : 61
```

I'm having a real tough time figuring out how to go through this data and figure out if any of the 'connection-status' is 'disconnected'.  I would use the same logic to determine if the engine-id is 0 or 1.  Can anyone here point me in the right direction?

Comment: Try this:
$xmldata.'engine-id'
I don't recall having to do this for dashes but this should work. If not please post your raw content ( result of $resp.rawcontent ) so we can take a look under the covers at what is happening.

Comment: You mean, something like `$xmldata.DiscoveryConnectionListingResponse.DiscoveryConnectionSummary | Where-Object {$_.connection-status -eq "Disconnected" }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hackerman's comment will filter out the disconnected `connection-status`:

```
$xmldata.DiscoveryConnectionListingResponse.DiscoveryConnect‌​ionSummary | Where-Object {$_."connection-status" -eq "Disconnected" }
```

Bear in mind you can easily loop over xml nodes in PowerShell:

```
foreach($node in $xmldata.DiscoveryConnectionListingResponse.DiscoveryConnectionSummary){

    if($node."connection-status" -eq "disconnected"{
        # do something
        Write-Output "ID $($node.id) with engine ID $($node."engine-id") is disconnected"
    }else{
        # do something else
    }

}
```